# Los datos en Ionic-Angular no se muestran al salir y al volver otra vez a la misma pagina

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy creando una aplicación en Ionic y Angular, pero tengo el siguiente problema al momento de visualizar los datos:
Tengo mi menú que me manda los distintos apartados de mi pagina, al entrar a un apartado me muestra la lista de los datos que hay en el que son traídos de Firebase, al entrar si me los muestra pero al salir y al volver otra vez ya no los muestra. ¿A que se debe? ¿Es un problema con la navegación o como estoy trayendo los datos?

Navegación

```
<ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>

      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item button [routerLink]="['/lista']">Lista1</ion-item> 
          <ion-item button [routerLink]="['/lista2']">Lista2</ion-item>

        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
```

Apartado lista.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TaskI} from '../../modelos/task.interface';
import {ListaService} from '../../modelos/lista.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coyoacan',
  templateUrl: './lista.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista.page.scss'],

})
export class ListaPage implements OnInit {
  todos: TaskI[];
  constructor(private listaService:ListaService) {   }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.listaService.getTodos().subscribe(res=>{
      this.todos=res;});
    }


}
```

Este es mi servicio:  lista.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection}  from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {TaskI} from '../modelos/task.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListaService {
  private todosCollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<TaskI>;
private todos:Observable<TaskI[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.todosCollection=db.collection<TaskI>('Lista');
  this.todos=this.todosCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(
   actions =>{
     return actions.map(a =>{
       const data =a.payload.doc.data();
       const id=a.payload.doc.id;
       return {id,...data};
     });
   }

  ));
  }
  getTodos(){
    return this.todos;

   }
   getTodo(id:string){
   return this.todosCollection.doc<TaskI>(id).valueChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yo también tengo exactamente el mismo problema. Estoy verificando(con tu código y el mio) que no sea un problema del ciclo de vida del componente. Al parecer cada evento se ejecuta en el momento justo... **El problema parece ser que al volver a la pagina ya no se renderizan los datos en el archivo HTML**  ... Voy a estar al pendiente a las posibles soluciones...